# Failed to install electron "tunneling socket could not be established"

Tags: node.js, windows-10, electron, npm-install

I am trying to install Electron on windows 10 using these commands:

```
- git clone https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start
- cd electron-quick-start
- npm install
- npm start
```

I already set the environment variables

```
USERPROFILE%/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin

%USERPROFILE%/AppData/Roaming/npm
```

I am following in the footsteps of this [**site**](https://electronjs.org/), but I am still getting these errors when giving **npm install**

### Error:

```
PS C:\Users\PC\Desktop\project\electron-quick-start> npm install

> electron@6.0.11 postinstall C:\Users\PC\Desktop\project\electron-quick-start\node_modules\electron
> node install.js

Downloading tmp-15380-0-electron-v6.0.11-win32-x64.zip
Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80
C:\Users\PC\Desktop\project\electron-quick-start\node_modules\electron\install.js:49
  throw err
  ^

Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80
    at ClientRequest.onError (C:\Users\PC\Desktop\project\electron-quick-start\node_modules\tunnel-agent\index.js:177:17)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:286:20)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:392:9)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:91:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:59:3)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
npm WARN rollback Rolling back debug@2.6.9 failed (this is probably harmless): EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir 'C:\Users\PC\Desktop\project\electron-quick-start\node_modules\sumchecker\node_modules'
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! electron@6.0.11 postinstall: `node install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the electron@6.0.11 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\PC\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-10-08T15_02_16_542Z-debug.log
PS C:\Users\PC\Desktop\project\electron-quick-start>
```

Here is the **[log](https://pastebin.com/QeJvDJZ8)** that was generated

So far, the node I use is as up to date as possible with version **10.16.3** and npm **6.11.3**.

What should I do to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

Try the Below :

```
npm config set proxy http://yourproxyaddress:port
npm config set https-proxy http://yourproxyaddress:port
npm config set strict-ssl false
```

I.E

```
npm config set registry=http://registry.npmjs.org/
npm config set strict-ssl false
```

This should fix the error your getting. If all fails you might have add the following in .npmrc

```
registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/
proxy=http://username:password@127.0.0.1:8888
https-proxy=http://username:password@127.0.0.1:8888
http-proxy=http://username:password@127.0.0.1:8888
strict-ssl=false
ca=null
```

Comment: @Sérgio Try the above & let me know the error you receive.